# how update more than one records on datagridview

Tags: c#, point-of-sale

i wrote the update coding below. i can add the record in the database successfully but when i update the qty it won't update only 1 record has been updated. ex. qty on point of sale system. when the customer buy the items enter we enter the pos . there are so item item buying by the customer. qty will reduce each and every items recorded in the pos system. but when i press update it couldn't updated  all item qty in the datagridview qty column please help me on this

public void update db()
        {

```
            for (int row = 0; row < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; row++)
            {
                string itmno = dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                string itmqty = dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                 string t = "select * from products where id=" + itmno + "";


                // Connnew.DbSearch(t);

                con.Close();




                     string oldqty = "", newqty = "";
            Connnew.DbSearch(t);
            while (Connnew.dr.Read())
            {
                oldqty = Connnew.dr[5].ToString();
                newqty = (int.Parse(oldqty) - int.Parse(itmqty)).ToString();
            }

            string t2 = "update products set qty=" + newqty + " where id=" + itmno + "";
            //t2 = t2.Replace("{0}", itmno);
            //t2 = t2.Replace("{2}", newqty);
            Connnew.DbUpdate(t2);
        }
```